# Show intermediate values obtained from native code in Android

Tags: android, c++, logging

I have some intermediate values which are generated during the execution of my native code in c++. Is there any way to print those values either as a toast or some log message.

I tried to print the values as a log, but it didn't work

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "No of matches", "%d", (int) matchings.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

That method should write the message to Logcat. If you're using a custom build process, be sure to link your NDK code against `liblog` (with `-l log`). For example:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc my_module.c -l log -o my_module
```